# Create PDF with images vertically inline with iText7 without new page

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

When I do a foreach loop in C# code to add images using iText7, the following code will add each image to a new page. How do I update this code, so it adds each image one after another on the pages and overflows to the next page if an image doesn't fit?

```cs
foreach (string imagePath in images) {
  // Add image
  iText.Layout.Element.Image img = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(ImageDataFactory
    .Create(imagePath))
    .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
  document.Add(img);
}
```

I also tried to create a div element and add the images to that, however only the first image was added, and it bled out across the first page.

```cs
Div div = new Div();

foreach (string imagePath in images) {
  // Add image
  div.add(new iText.Layout.Element.Image(ImageDataFactory
    .create(imagePath)
    .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)));
}

// Add the div to the document
doc.add(div);
```

How do I add images one after another using iText7?

Comment: @KJ If I know the number of images, and they are the same size, and I can work out how many will fit per page, how do I add them vertically? I can add a new page then put 3 vertically on the next page and go on from that. Do you know how that's done at least?

Comment: If iText puts the images onto different pages, then that is because they don't fit together onto a single one.

Comment: Can you update your question with some extra information: page size and orientation,  image sizes, and expected image size in the document?